# Inkscape: How to skew a circle

Tags: inkscape, skew

I sometimes skew a square to make a sort of 3D layer. (as in the picture below).
I do this by converting the object to path and then dragging the 2 left nodes up. 
The same technique does not work with a circle, now I am wondering if I can do a similar effect with circles.
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In order to skew an object you don't necessary need to convert it to path.

You can click twice on the object and use the side arrows to [skew](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Transforms.html) it:

[image: Skew an object]

Please note that exists also a *Perspective* tool in the *Extension* menu.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. Thanks!

Comment: Always glad to help. Every day I discover new things.